# Percentage-based CSS Grid with IE6+ support?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, percentage, grid-layout

I'm looking for a lightweight percentage-based CSS grid system (preferably 12 columns) that has proven compatibility with IE6+ and all modern browsers. Also, this is not an absolute necessity, but support for nested columns would be nice. Most of the grid systems I've found either don't support IE6 or are only pixel-based widths.

Thanks!

Comment: 12 columns of unknown width comes down to 8.3333333333(etc)% which means they will always differ some in the width (one pixels here and there). But if you set that width to your 12 columns you should be good.

Comment: IE6 support has been dropped by Microsoft and auto updated to IE7 for just about everyone who is connected to the internet. Why exactly do you need support for IE6?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a recommendation engine.

Comment: @ryan Yeah I know, its mainly to satisfy project requirements, as this will be used for many public-facing websites created for my company's clients. Worldwide usage is still at 6% worldwide, so theoretically these sites might still be accessed via IE6. Diodeus -I've seen a TON of questions asking for recommendations for programming frameworks/plugins/ect, and no one fussed over it.. its still a valid programming related question imo..

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: http://www.tinyfluidgrid.com/

also, i think you should give this a read: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/